# Generate individual H5 files for each and every video

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, deep-learning, pytorch

My code is about to create an `H5 file` for Each and Every video in the folder, Extracting the feature from the video and stored into the `H5 file`.

in Below shown `code` extraction feature from `multi videos` and all the features are stored in the `single H5 file`

**H5 file order:**

```
video1:
   - feature 
video2:
   - feature
```

**issues:**

- How to create an H5 file for every video after a process is done

**Code**: `Create_data.py`

```
import argparse
from utils.generate_dataset import Generate_Dataset

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(""Welcome you to fraction)
# Dataset options

parser.add_argument('--input', '--split', type=str, help="input video")
parser.add_argument('--output', type=str, default='', help="out data")

args = parser.parse_args()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    gen = Generate_Dataset(args.input, args.output)
    gen.generate_dataset()
    gen.h5_file.close()
```

Code: `Generate_Dataset.py :`

```
import os
from networks.CNN import ResNet
from utils.KTS.cpd_auto import cpd_auto
from tqdm import tqdm
import math
import cv2
import numpy as np
import h5py
import numpy as np

class Generate_Dataset:
    def __init__(self, video_path, save_path):
        self.resnet = ResNet()
        self.dataset = {}
        self.video_list = []
        self.video_path = ''
        self.h5_file = h5py.File(save_path, 'w')

        self._set_video_list(video_path)

    def _set_video_list(self, video_path):
        # import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        if os.path.isdir(video_path):
            self.video_path = video_path
            fileExt = r".mp4",".avi"
            self.video_list = [_ for _ in os.listdir(video_path) if _.endswith(fileExt)]
            self.video_list.sort()
        else:
            self.video_path = ''
            
            self.video_list.append(video_path)

        for idx, file_name in enumerate(self.video_list):
            self.dataset['video_{}'.format(idx+1)] = {}
            self.h5_file.create_group('video_{}'.format(idx+1))


    def _extract_feature(self, frame):
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (224, 224))
        res_pool5 = self.resnet(frame)
        frame_feat = res_pool5.cpu().data.numpy().flatten()

        return frame_feat

    def _get_change_points(self, video_feat, n_frame, fps):
        n = n_frame / fps
        m = int(math.ceil(n/2.0))
        K = np.dot(video_feat, video_feat.T)
        change_points, _ = cpd_auto(K, m, 1)
        change_points = np.concatenate(([0], change_points, [n_frame-1]))

        temp_change_points = []
        for idx in range(len(change_points)-1):
            segment = [change_points[idx], change_points[idx+1]-1]
            if idx == len(change_points)-2:
                segment = [change_points[idx], change_points[idx+1]]

            temp_change_points.append(segment)
        change_points = np.array(list(temp_change_points))

        # temp_n_frame_per_seg = []
        # for change_points_idx in range(len(change_points)):
        #     n_frame = change_points[change_points_idx][1] - change_points[change_points_idx][0]
        #     temp_n_frame_per_seg.append(n_frame)
        # n_frame_per_seg = np.array(list(temp_n_frame_per_seg))
        # print(change_points)
        arr = change_points
        list1 = arr.tolist()
        list2 = list1[-1].pop(1) #pop [-1]value 
        print(list2)
        print(list1)
        
        print("****************") # [-1][-1] value find and divided by 15
       
        cps_m = math.floor(arr[-1][1]/15)
        list1[-1].append(cps_m)             #append to list 
        print(list1)
        
        print("****************") #list to nd array convertion
        
        arr = np.asarray(list1)
        print(arr)

        arrmul = arr * 15
        print(arrmul)

        print("****************")   
        # print(type(change_points))
        # print(n_frame_per_seg)
        # print(type(n_frame_per_seg))
        median_frame = []
        for x in arrmul:
          print(x)
          med = np.mean(x)
          print(med)
          int_array = med.astype(int)
          median_frame.append(int_array)
        print(median_frame)
        #   print(type(int_array))
        return arrmul

    # TODO : save dataset
    def _save_dataset(self):
        pass

    def generate_dataset(self):
        print('[INFO] CNN processing')
        for video_idx, video_filename in enumerate(self.video_list):
            video_path = video_filename
            if os.path.isdir(self.video_path):
                video_path = os.path.join(self.video_path, video_filename)
            video_basename = os.path.basename(video_path).split('.')[0]
            video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
            fps = video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
            n_frames = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
            frame_list = []
            picks = []
            video_feat = None
            video_feat_for_train = None
            for frame_idx in tqdm(range(n_frames-1)):
                success, frame = video_capture.read()
                if frame_idx % 15 == 0:

                    if success:

                        frame_feat = self._extract_feature(frame)                    
                        picks.append(frame_idx)

                        if video_feat_for_train is None:
                            video_feat_for_train = frame_feat
                        else:
                            video_feat_for_train = np.vstack((video_feat_for_train, frame_feat))
                        if video_feat is None:
                            video_feat = frame_feat
                        else:
                            video_feat = np.vstack((video_feat, frame_feat))
                    else:
                        break
            video_capture.release()
            arrmul = self._get_change_points(video_feat, n_frames, fps)
            self.h5_file['video_{}'.format(video_idx+1)]['features'] = list(video_feat_for_train)
            self.h5_file['video_{}'.format(video_idx+1)]['picks'] = np.array(list(picks))
            self.h5_file['video_{}'.format(video_idx+1)]['n_frames'] = n_frames
            self.h5_file['video_{}'.format(video_idx+1)]['fps'] = fps
            self.h5_file['video_{}'.format(video_idx + 1)]['video_name'] = video_filename.split('.')[0]
            self.h5_file['video_{}'.format(video_idx+1)]['change_points'] = arrmul
```

Expected results :

```
Folder: video
          video_1:
              video1.mp4
              video2.mp4
```

Files are in this structure, now read video files and create separate H5 files after the process is over.

[For more Code reference](https://github.com/Chuttyboy/H5_Generation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to :

1. remove `self.h5_file = h5py.File(save_path, 'w')` from `__init__()`
2. remove `self.h5_file.create_group('video_{}'.format(idx+1))` from `_set_video_list()`
3. remove `gen.h5_file.close()` from `main()`
4. change last block of `generate_dataset()` into something like:

.

```
video_capture.release()
arrmul = self._get_change_points(video_feat, n_frames, fps)

h5_dir = os.path.dirname(video_path)
h5_full_path = os.path.join(h5_dir, 'video_{}'.format(video_idx+1))
with h5py.File(h5_full_path, 'w') as h5_file:
   h5_file['features'] = list(video_feat_for_train)
   h5_file['picks'] = np.array(list(picks))
   h5_file['n_frames'] = n_frames
   h5_file['fps'] = fps
   h5_file['video_name'] = video_filename.split('.')[0]
   h5_file['change_points'] = arrmul
```

Please note that your inner video file indices and actual video file name numbers may not match. So I suggest to change

```
h5_dir = os.path.dirname(video_path)
h5_full_path = os.path.join(h5_dir, 'video_{}'.format(video_idx+1))
```

from above into

```
h5_full_path = video_path.split('.')[0] + '.h5'
```

This will create features file with the name matched to the video file.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and it will be very helpful for me, processing H5 file created successfully but nothing inside h5 file how to pass data to h5 file

Comment: This is very strange behavior. Once you create the container with `h5py.File()` you put data in it just by creating a new key: for example `h5_file['my_random_data'] = np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000)`. Once you close the container (by leaving `with` scope and thus releasing the handle) it will write down the changes. If you don't use `with` you will need to explicitly close the container by `h5_file.close()`.

Comment: I need one more help from you .... How can do this in parallel..is this possible? if yes how can I do that?

Comment: It is possible, but not trivial. You will need to create a function that accepts video file name and creates features file, create a pool of parallel workers that apply that function and submit each video file to one of the workers. See [this post](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/python/parallel-processing-python/) for example. (use `Pool.apply()`)